# If in for-loop not working even though the condition is satisfied

Tags: python

Running the following code to compare values in a column of a text file to a given number, in this case 440

```
with open('test.txt', 'a+') as input:
 for line in input:
  columns = line.split(" ")
  print columns[5] #test
  if columns[5] == '440':
   print 'match'
```

test.txt is just:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 440
0 0 0 0 0 1   
0 0 0 0 0 440
0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The print columns[5] bit prints out the right value from the txt file, but even when it matches 440, the if inside the for-loop doesnt work

thank you for any help

Comment: Please use `print repr(columns[5])` instead and show us the output of that.

Comment: Do you really intend to open the file in mode `'a+'`? That's an *append* mode.

Comment: If your text file does really contain numbers, then why are you not comparing it like: - `int(columns[0]) == 440`?

Answer (score 5):

Since your 440 is the last thing on the line, `column[5] == '440\n'`

You need to strip the values before comparing.

```
if columns[5].strip() == '440':
```

or strip it first:

```
columns = line.strip().split(" ")
```

or use the general split, which will split on all whitespace:

```
columns = line.split()
```

Or do an actual number comparison

```
if int(columns[5]) == 440:
```

Comment: or simply use `split()`, it takes care of these whitespaces, `columns = line.split()`.

Comment: @Nicolas Good call. Edited.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: no, `.split()` without any arguments at all, or `None` as the first positional argument, strips whitespace from start and end, then splits on variable width whitespace (including newlines and tabs).